# Узнать где на сайте битая ссылка

Tags: seo

Нашел битую ссылку. А вот как ее найти на сайте, т.е. в каком месте она?

Comment: `Нашел`....`как ее найти`......ох...

Comment: спросите разработчика сайта

Comment: Очень трудно искать битую ссылку на незнакомом сайте. Особенно если ее там нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы нашли ее в логах, то смотрите Referer - с какой страницы пришел человек, а там уже в коде ищите. Кроме того, битая ссылка может оказаться результатом опечатки на стороннем ресурсе или сбоем в каком-то роботе.